# Supress "true" statement & skip blank rows when importing text from Excel to Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba

I have reached a few steps along the way to set up a standard template for Outlook emails in Excel 2016.

I would like to import comments into my email from the B column if the A column in the same row is marked with an "x". The comments comes from a sheet with many different ones to choose from (the idea is that one can pick the ones applicable for every individual email to save some time and standardize the procedure across the department).

The import is accomplished by running a For-loop over all the rows containing a comment.
However, the script also writes "True" before every copied comment and table in my email.
Furthermore, for every imported comment it adds a blank row.

1. How can I supress the "true" statement for the comments in my email?
2. How can I supress the "true" statement for the table in my email?
3. How can import the comments without the extra blank row between them?

This is the part of my code for importing the cells containing a comment marked with "x" and a table:

```vb
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With OutlookMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    .Subject = "Sizing Calculations - " & Range("C37")
    .To = Range("C34").Value
    .Display

    Set xInspect = OutlookMail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

    .HTMLBody = "ASSUMPTIONS:" & "<br><br>"
    'Set range to cover the assumptions to choose from
    For i = 2 To 14
        Sheets("COMMENTS").Select
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "x" Then
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & _
            Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).Copy
            pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
            pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
            pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        End If
    Next i

    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & _
    "SIZING:" & "<br><br>" & _
    Sheets("TABLES").Range("N1:P6").Value
    Sheets("TABLES").Range("N1:P6").Copy
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

End With
```

My email comments turn out like this (in this case two comments are marked with "x"):

ASSUMPTIONS:

TrueCa(OH)2 quality: BET surface > 15 m2/g

TrueWater quality: default values

Comment: Welcome to SO, Not sure about this but `.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & _
            Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).Copy` shouln't be something like `.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & _
            Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).value`?

Comment: Please, add that new extra info to original questio. Edit and update so everybody can read and maybe help. The easier is your question to read, the best the help you will get

Comment: Yes, separating the two commands into separate lines fixes my first issue with the "true" statement for the comments! Great, thanks.  `Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).Value          Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).Copy `

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Only, now the second comment gets copied two times into the email. I'm confused haha.

Comment: Why are you using Copy?

Comment: To copy the cell with the comment in it, and then paste it into the HTML body of the email I am generating. I have tried to remove the copy command, but then the code just omits to import the comment to the email.

Comment: To add the value in the cell, you can just do `.HTMLBody & _ Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).value ` This will concatenate all the text inside variable `.HTMLBody` with the value of the cell `Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).value`

Comment: Ah, I got it. Using :          ´If Cells(i, 1).Value = "x" Then
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "- " & _
            Sheets("COMMENTS").Range("B" & i).Value
            End If´        Removes both the "true" statement and the extra space.      Do you have any idea how to fix the "true" statement on the tables?